# Regex to extract a line in which the first word ends in a vowel

Tags: regex, grep

Actually I'm beginner in regex.
I managed to do the following:

`egrep '[aeiou]\b'` - the last character for each word is a vowel

`egrep '^[^ ]+'` - first word of line

But I have no idea how to write regex to match my task. I will be very grateful if you could help me.

Comment: You probably need `egrep '^\w+[aeiou]\b'`

Comment: Try `grep '^[[:alpha:]]*[aeiou]\b'` or [`grep '^[[:alpha:]]*[aeiou]\>'`](http://rextester.com/WBOOAI23183).

Comment: Could you please share what the OS and `grep` version are?

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 Precise Pangolin. Actually I don't know how to check version of grep

Comment: So, does `grep '^[[:alpha:]]*[aeiou]\b'` work?

Comment: Yes, it works perfectly. Thank you

Comment: @Valentyn I posted an answer below, with explanation and demo. If you need more help please let know.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may match the start of a line with `^`, then match any amount of letters using `[[:alpha:]]*` and then match the vowel with `[aeiuo]` and then assert a trailing word boundary (`\b` or `\>`):

```
grep  '^[[:alpha:]]*[aeiou]\b'
grep  '^[[:alpha:]]*[aeiou]\>'
```

Tested in Ubuntu:

[image]

Comment: To complicate things, this can be a better (pc)re: `(?i)(?<=^\s*)[a-z]*[aeiou]\b`. Needs support for variable-length lookbehinds, though.

Comment: Well, if you put it that way, there is no need in a lookbehind, `grep -iP '^\s*\p{L}*[aeiou]\b'` and `grep -P '(?i)^\s*\p{L}*[aeiou]\b'` work, too.